# How to convert data format in JSON using SED

Tags: json, sed

I have a huge NDJSON file wherein one field is `"createDate":"01/02/2018"`. It is in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and I need to convert it into `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

I can do this using `sed` on a small input using the below command:

```
echo 28/02/2018 | sed 's,\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-1][0-9]\)/\([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]\),\3-\2-\1,'
```

However, I'm unable to find a solution wherein I have to do this in a JSON file where this value is under a key with name `"createDate"`.

A sample JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "pushNotificationEnabled": "true",
    "createDate": "11/08/2018",
    "email": null,
    "photoUrl": null
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works on your sample JSON object! You might want to restrict its action to the `createDate` field:

```
sed '/"createDate":/s,\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-1][0-9]\)/\([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]\),\3-\2-\1,' input.json
```

This will only affect lines containing the `"createDate":` tag:

```
==> input.json <==
{
    "pushNotificationEnabled": "true",
    "createDate": "11/08/2018",
    "modifyDate": "31/08/2018",
    "email": null,
    "photoUrl": null
  }
$ sed '/"createDate":/s,\([0-9][0-9]\)/\([0-1][0-9]\)/\([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]\),\3-\2-\1,' input.json
{
    "pushNotificationEnabled": "true",
    "createDate": "2018-08-11",
    "modifyDate": "31/08/2018",
    "email": null,
    "photoUrl": null
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each object in the NDJSON file will fit comfortably in memory, an invocation of [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) along the following lines should do the job, regardless of how large the file itself is, because jq will (by default) only read in one JSON entity at a time:

```
jq '.createDate |=
    sub("^(?<m>[0-9]*)/(?<d>[0-9]*)/(?<y>[0-9]*)"; "\(.y)-\(.m)-\(.d)")' input.json
```

Although jq might be slightly less efficient than sed for the task, it does understand JSON.